Find the limit of the recurrence relation: $x_n = p^n + (1-(p^n + (1-p)^n)) x_{n-1}$
Given the recurrence relation:
$$x_n = p^n + (1-(p^n + (1-p)^n)) x_{n-1}$$
where $p\in (0,1)$ is a fixed parameter and $n=1,2,3,\dots$
I am struggling to calculate the limit of the sum when $n \to \infty$.
If the recurrence relation had been simplified as follows:
$$x_n = p^n + x_{n-1}$$
it is easy to see that the partial sum is:
$$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n p^i$$
and converges to:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S(n) = \frac{p}{1-p} $$
In reality, however, the coefficient preceding the term $x_{n-1}$ is not constant and only approaches one when $n \to \infty$
This is probably a fairly simple question to solve, but I can't figure it out.
Thank you to everyone who would like to help me!
UPDATE:
Thank you very much for your valuable answers!
As Thomas Andrews argued, I've written this recursive equation from the idea of playing the following game: "$n$ coins, each with probability $p$ of heads, are flipped simultaneously. There are two players. If all the coins are heads, Player 1 wins. If all the coins are tails, Player 2 wins. If neither Player 1 nor Player 2 wins, one coin is discarded and the remaining $n-1$ coins are flipped again. This process is repeated until one of the two players wins.  I'd calculate the probability of Player 1 winning the game. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that Player 1 is our main character and just call him/her "the player".
So let's start with a very simple situation where there are only $n=2$ coins. The probability that the player wins the game is equal to $p^2$ (if the player heads with both coins) or $p$ if the player heads with only one coin. However, for it to be possible to play with only one coin, it is necessary that neither player has won, and this happens with probability $2p(1-p)$ or equivalently with probability $1-(p^2 + (1-p)^2) $. So the probability of the player winning the game with only two coins is equal to $p^2 + 2p(1-p)p = -2p^3 + 3p^2 $ . Now we note that while it is true that $-2p^3 + 3p^2 < p$ for $0<p<1/2$, this does not seem to be a necessary and sufficient condition for the series to converge, since I have heuristically found that the sum converges even for $p>1/2$.
If we take p=0.4 as an example, we see that:



n
$x_n$




1
0.4


2
0.352


3
0.31744


4
0.293773312


5
0.278161260544


...
...


$\ge 68$
0.251802834962308



The calculated probabilities in this table are not approximations. You will notice that for $n\ge 68$ the probability of winning converges to exactly 0.251802834962308 without ever changing.
This is true even if we choose a p>1/2, e.g. p=0.8:



n
$x_n$




1
0.8


2
0.896


3
0.94208


4
0.964296704


5
0.975687385088


...
...


$\ge 141$
0.994101487772863



From $n \ge 141$ the probability of winning converges to exactly 0.994101487772863 without ever changing further.
Empirical tests, which anyone can do with a calculator, actually seem to suggest that, for sufficiently large $n$ (i.e. for $n \to \infty$) the sum converges to a limit probability for any chosen $p\in (0,1)$. Interestingly, the plot (p,$f(p)$) of the empirically calculated limit probabilities seems to suggest the following Richards's curve:
$$f(p) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-B(p-0.5)}}$$  for some growth rate B. Of course, this function is very flat at the lower and upper bounds of p.
I therefore wondered whether there was a closed formula for calculating the limit for $n \to \infty$ of this probability, having fixed a certain value of p, in order to be able to derive the value of B, but judging from the answers received, it seems that such a closed formula does not exist.

This looks like an interesting problem. Can you share a bit of the context where it arose?

Is there a reason to expect a closed formula?
Not an answer, just some observations.
$x_n$ will be a polynomial in $p$ of degree $n(n+1)/2.$
The recurrence says $x_1=p.$
We will get the ugly formula $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p^k \prod_{j=k+1}^n\left(1-p^j-(1-p)^j\right)\tag1$$
We can easily see that the polynomial $x_n(p)$ is divisible by $p^n$, since $1-p^j-(1-p)^j$ is always divisible by $p$, so the product in $(1)$ is always divisible by $p^{n-k}.$
We can see that $x_n(p)+x_n(1-p)=1.$ That can be seen by induction, or by expressing this problem as a question about a game:

Given a coin with probability $p$ of heads, we flip the coin $n$ times. If you get all heads, then player $1$ wins, if all tails, then player $2$ wins, and otherwise, we start again, this time flipping the coin $n-1$ times.

$x_n(p)$ is the probability player $1$ wins and $x_n(1-p)$ the probability player $2$ wins, and, since there are no draws, $x_n(p)+x_n(1-p)=1.$
This game also says that $x_n(p)$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1),$ because the probability of player $1$ winning definitely goes up as th probability of a heads goes up. Also $x_n(1)=1$ and $x_n(1/2)=1/2.$
If $p=1/2+r,$ we define $f(r)=x_n(\frac12+r)-\frac12$ satisfies $f(r)=-f(-r),$ so $f$ is an odd polynomial in $r,$ so $$x_n(p)=\frac12+f\left(p-\frac12\right)=\frac12+\sum a_i\left(p-\frac12\right)^{2i-1}$$
For some coefficients $a_i.$

The series cannot converge to a power series, since $x_n(p)$ is divisible by $p^n$ for all $n,$ so in the limit, the function has to be very very flat at $p=0.$ Similarly, $x_n(p)$ is very very flat at $1.$
This already explains why the limit is tricky.
If we try to play the game in reverse, and let $N_1$ be the largest value where we get all heads and $N_2$ be the largest value we get all tails - we set both value to $0$ if the never occur. We get: $
So, $$f(p)=P(N_1>N_2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^{n}\prod_{m=n+1}^\infty (1-p^m-(1-p)^m)$$
If $g(p)=\prod_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-p^m-(1-p)^m),$ then we can rewrite this as:
$$f(p)=g(p)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p^n}{\prod_{m=2}^n (1-p^m-(1-p)^m)}$$
The inside products converge to non-zero values when $p\in(0,1),$ but each term in the product is divisible by $p$ and $1-p.$ So again, we get very flat functions near $p=0$ and $p=1.$ Each product is less than $1.$
We know $N_1\neq N_2$ except when their values are infinite, which is probability $0.$ So we know $f(p)+f(1-p)=1.$

Actually, before investigating the value of the sum, notice that the sum diverges for some values of $p$ !
For the case $p>\frac{1}{2}$, $x_n\not\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ so the sum surely diverges.
Here's the proof. First, you can convince yourself that $x_n \geq x_{n-1} \iff x_{n-1}\leq \frac{p^n}{p^n+(1-p)^n}=f(n).$
Note that since $p>\frac{1}{2}$, $f$ is an increasing function and $f(n)\leq f(n+1)$ for all $n$.
Let $x_1=p$. As $p=f(1)$, we have $x_1\leq f(1)\leq f(2)$ and then $x_2\geq x_1$.
Suppose by induction that $x_{n-1}\leq f(n)$, $n\geq 1$. Then $x_n\leq f(n+1)$. Here's why. We have:
\begin{align*}
x_{n} &\leq p^n + (1-(p^n+(1-p)^n))f(n) \\
 &\leq p^n + f(n) - (p^n +(1-p)^n)f(n) \\
&\leq p^n + f(n) - p^n = f(n)\\
&\leq f(n+1)
\end{align*}
Therefore, the sequence is increasing as soon as $p>\frac{1}{2}$, and so the general term $x_n > x_1=p > 0$ does not converge to $0$.
When $p=\frac{1}{2}$, all terms $x_n$ are trivially equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and the sum diverges as well.
When $p<\frac{1}{2}$, numerical experiments shows that $(x_n)$ seems to decrease to $0$, but I have not checked the proof; nor the possible value of the sum.
